# rails/devise data consistency when inviting users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, devise

At the moment I have a user and a product table and products are created by users. So the user can create his own product he is working on. 
User `has_many :products` and 
product `belongs_to :user`.

Now I'd like to provide the user to be able to add more users to the product (who worked on product with him/her) even if those are not registered yet in the app.

So I will change the product and user table connection to has_many :users, through: :ProductUsers and has_many :products, through: :ProductUsers.

Then when the user creates a product and adds the extra name and the email of the other users in the form the app will send out emails to those people to register (only if they are not registered). I can manage this far.

So here is my problem: The product is already created with the added names and emails when the email invitation is sent out.

- How can I make sure that after registration the new user entity will be assigned to the product his email and name is already assigned to by the guy who created the product?
- How can I make sure the data will be consistent?
- What kinda table should contain the email/name when product is created?
- Is the approach for the table the good one or I should differentiate the creator and other users somehow for some authorization reasons?

I hope my question is clear :)